# Laravel 5 command - Mandatory options

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to write a laravel command but I can't have the options to be mandatory.

I do understand that the concept of option is being "optional" but I'd like to have a command in which it is clear which input you are inserting and in no particular order.

i.e. 
I would like to achieve this, with par2 and par 2 mandatory

```
$command-abc --par1=value1 --par2=value2
```

Instead of:

```
$command-abc value1 value2
```

So far this is the signature I used:

```
protected $signature = 'dst-comparison:analyse
                        {--client : Client Name}
                        {--clientId : Client ID}
                        {--recordingId : Client Recording ID}
                        {--CSVFile : Path to the downloaded CSV file from Spotify analytics}
                        {--dataUpdateTo=null : CSV Data will be truncated from this date onwards}';
```

Following the Laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan) and this guide: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/your-one-stop-guide-to-laravel-commands--net-30349 it seemed that overwriting the getOptions method was doing the trick, but it is not working for me.

```
/**
 * Get the console command options.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        array('client', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Client Name'),
        array('clientId', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Client ID'),
        array('recordingId', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Client Recording ID'),
        array('CSVFile', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Path to the downloaded CSV file from Spotify analytics'),
        array('dataUpdateTo', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'CSV Data will be truncated from this date onwards')
    );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Validate the options yourself, as @Kjell suggests. Like you say, options are meant to be _optional_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to take care of mandatory input yourself. Have a look at the various output functions `$this->error(...)` and check if all necessary input was given `$this->option('client');` (<- returns `null` if no input was defined)

https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to make something more generic and take advantage of Laravel Validation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation, follow this approach:

- create an abstract `BaseCommand.php`, and add Validator there
- extend that BaseCommand in your custom command `myCustomCommand.php`

#BaseCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace Your\NameSpace;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Validator;
abstract class BaseCommand extends Command {
    public $rules;
    
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($rules) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->rules = $rules;
    }
    
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->handleAfterValidation();
        }
    }
    
    public function validate() {
        $validator = Validator::make($this->option(), $this->rules);
        if (!$validator->passes()) {
            $this->error($validator->messages());
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    abstract public function handleAfterValidation();
}
```

#myCustomCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace Your\NameSpace;
use Validator;
use Your\NameSpace\BaseCommand;
class SendEmail extends BaseCommand {
    public $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'age' => 'required|numeric',
        'name' => 'required|string'
    ];
    
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'mycmd:Whatever {--email=} {--age=} {--name=}';
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Add description';
    
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->rules);
    }
    
    public function handleAfterValidation() {
        // DO something here with $this->option('email'), $this->option('age'), $this->option('name')
    }
}
```